# How do I format a string within a function call?

Tags: python, string, python-2.6

I want to pass a string to a variable to a string, which in turn gets passwd onto a function. I had written the code below:

**Not Working**

```
env = 'D'
myFunction("Checking Processes A%s/B%s",'')% (env,env)
```

**error**

```
myFunction("Checking Processes A%s/B%s",'')% (env,env)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Since the code failed I re-wrote it as below:

**Working**

```
env = 'D'
str = "Checking Processes A%s/B%s" %(env,env)
myFunction(str,'')
```

Can anyone suggest any alternative shorter approaches to this ?Ideally in lines of my first attemp which would mean less LOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myFunction("Checking Processes A%s/B%s" % (env,env),'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do this:

```
>>> "Checking Processes A{}/B{}".format(env,env)
'Checking Processes AD/BD'
```